# Linq query definition

Tags: c#, linq, azure-storage

I'm using the Windows Azure Toolkit product on codeplex. It looks perfect to meet my needs but there are very few examples out there. In particular there is a method to get data from Azure tables:

```
    public virtual T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return this.Query.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

The problem is there are NO examples in the toolkit and I can't understand what the argument:

```
 (Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
```

should look like.

Is there anyone out there with a knowledge of Linq and C# that could give me some advice or suggestions that I could try.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

It's just a predicate, a method that accepts a parameter of type `T` and returns a boolean - easiest way to use this is by passing a lambda expression - simple example:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> Query;

    public virtual T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return this.Query.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
...
Foo<int> foo = new Foo<int>();
int firstValueUnder100 = foo.Get(x => x <= 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example (return everything)

```
  foo.Get(x => true);
```

Answer (score 0):

brokenglass got there 1st, but another example would be:

`foo.Get(x => x.OrderID == paramid);`

where paramid was some arbitary parameter or variable etc